# How to make a Wordpress site handle a mouse event?

Tags: css, ajax, wordpress, events

I am trying to build an event handler that can work with a Wordpress site. Let me simplify what I want to do as follows:

The front-end has a button. If a user presses it, it rings a bell (or sounds a beep). Then the page shows how many people have so far rung the bell.

I understand that this involves both the client side and the server side, but what is the right architecture and code for doing this?

I am thinking of a server side php function that increments a variable to keep track of the total ring count. What do I use on the front-end to invoke the php function? Ajax? Or is there anyway I can do this with CSS alone?

Thanks for all help and suggestions.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Stack Overflow is not a coding service. You are expected to ***research your issue and make a good attempt to write the code yourself*** before posting. If you get stuck on something *specific*, come back and include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a summary of what you tried

Answer (score 1):

Here you will need to build two parts :

1) the first part will be the JS code related to the button which will send data using AJAX. You can add this code directly onto your theme files (footer.php for example) or using a plugin.

2) the second part is to build the PHP handler that will intercept the ajax call and update the database with the information. You can do this in the function.php of your theme.

What you will need to know is:

- How to use AJAX with Jquery since wordpress use jQuery
- You need to know how to add a PHP code to handle the ajax request, you can do this with "add_action('wp_ajax_you_action', 'function_of_your_action');
- Then how to manipulate wordpress DB to store the information

here is a link that may help you to see code samples :
https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/using-ajax-with-wordpress/

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I needed!!

Answer (score 0):

Add an Audio Tag on your website e.g. in footer.php, set it to display:none;... it doesn't have to be visible, it just have to play the file when you click the button. Naturally you'll need your Button and a div for your counter

```
//HTML 
//e.g. footer.php
<audio id="bell_audio" controls preload="auto">
    <source src="bell.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
    <source src="bell.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>

//BUTTON
<button id="bell_button">Play Bell</button>

//VISIBLE COUNTER
<div id="counter"><?php echo get_post_meta(3, 'bell-clicked')?></div>
```

With the following JS snippet you add a click function onto your button where it should play the bell and count the playings.

```
$('#bell_button').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({ 
        type: 'post', 
        url: 'path_to_your_WP_theme_folder/click-bell.ajax.php', 
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function () {
            // PLAYS THE AUDIO FILE
            $('#bell_audio').play();
        },
        success: function (data) { 
            // RECEIVES JSON ($updatedAmount) FROM PHP FILE AND UPDATES VISIBLE COUNTER
            $('#counter').html('data');
        },
        error : function(jqxhr,textStatus,error){
            console.log(textStatus + ", " + error);
        }
    });
});
```

In the JS Code you see a AJAX function which calls a PHP file called click-bell.ajax.php, this PHP file is only for reading how many times the bell was played and set it to +1.

```
<?php
/*
PHP FILE: click-bell.ajax.php 
Store Bell Click Amount on Home Page (e.g. ID:3)
*/
require_once('../../../wp-load.php');
if (!add_post_meta( 3, 'bell-clicked', '1', true)) : 
    $givenAmount = get_post_meta(3, 'bell-clicked');
    update_post_meta( 3, 'bell-clicked', $givenAmount+1);
endif;
$updatedAmount = get_post_meta(3, 'bell-clicked');

if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT']) && (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT'], 'application/json') !== false)) :
    header('Content-type: application/json');
else :
    header('Content-type: text/plain');
endif;
echo json_encode($updatedAmount);
```

With these 3 snippets you should be able you create your button and count how many times it was clicked... The button count is stored as a meta data on your home page, you can change the ID inside the php script as you want to save it on the page where your button is located

Hope I could help you